# Run command through child process on telnet server using node js

Tags: node.js, sockets

My requirement is to connect to telnet server from client side and run commands on server machine using nodejs.

Here is the code i am using:

```
const net = require("net");
const cp = require("child_process");

net.connect({host: 192.168.192.136, port:23}, function() {
    console.log("connected");
    cp.exec('pwd', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(stdout);
    });
});
```

With this i am able to connect to server but when i run command using `cp.exec` it is running on local machine not on connected server.

1) how to run that command on server after connection?

2) Why connection is established to server without username or password. although when i try to connect to it through terminal it asks for username and password.

I also tried with some node js modules from npmjs but didn't get success.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use remote-exce module to do the same.
Here link to documentation:-
https://www.npmjs.com/package/remote-exec

Comment: it is working for ssh connection. but not for telnet connection on port 23

Answer (score 0):

Then Use telnet client module
Link to documentation
https://www.npmjs.com/package/telnet-client

Comment: I have tried this also but it always return timeout error. I have raised this issue on its github page

Answer (score 0):

On Nodejs v15 I don't think you need `exec` for that. I've managed to establish a telnet connection via the following method:

```
const net = require("net");

/*
*    establish new client connection to the server
*/
let client = net.connect({
    host: "192.168.192.136", 
    port: 23,
}, ()=> {
    console.log("connected");
    client.write("TELNET COMMAND HERE", ()=>{
        console.log("Command sent!")
    })
});
```

Tutorial reference: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectlistener